# pyCharm Unresolved reference syntax highlighting

Tags: python, import, pycharm

I have a "false" unresolved reference in pyCharm.

I say "false" because the references can actually be executed, my code works fine, so I think it's more a pyCharm problem being unable to resolve the references and marks them in red.

Since I'm quite new to python I would like to understand where the problem comes from.

Basically in the code I'm dealing with, there's a

```
from PyDAQmx import *
```

and then in my code I use some of the functions/methods/constants of this library.

```
DAQmxCreateTask(...)
DAQmxStartTask(...)
```

PyCharm is marking this references in red with the message ``Unresolved reference DAQmxCreateTask`

If I do

```
from PyDAQmx import DAQmxCreateTask, DAQmxStartTask
```

or I do:

```
import PyDAQmx as PyDAQmx   
PyDAQmx.DAQmxCreateTask(...)
```

then the Unresolved reference disapears, so I actually have this two ways of solving my problem, but I want to understand why it happens.

I already tried the pyCharm option of "Invalidate caches and restart" without success.

To my understanding if you do a `from foo import *` then all functions inside foo should be resolved and callable.

Example.

```
>> linspace(0,10,3)
Unresolved reference linspace

>> from numpy import *
>> linspace(0,10,3)
array([ 0.,  5., 10.])
```

So that means that numpy has "something" that allows pycharm to resolve it's functions when imported using * but PyDAQmx lacks this "something"

Could someone guide me in understanding wht this "something" is and how to solve it?

Comment: While it is not likely what is causing the problem, `from foo import *` is generally regarded as poor coding style these days. You should import the objects/classes you need explicitly.

Comment: While it is not likely what is causing the problem, `from foo import *` is generally regarded as poor coding style these days. You should import the objects/classes you need explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

`PyDAQmx` is defining these functions dynamically by adding them to the `globals()` dict (from the file `'/Applications/National Instruments/NI-DAQmx Base/includes/NIDAQmxBase.h'`), so I would guess that PyCharm's static code analysis of 3rd party libraries can't identify `DAQmxCreateTask` due to this.

You can see this in the dynamic definition of `__all__` in the `PyDAQmx` library, while `numpy` doesn't do this. `__all__` restricts the symbols available after a `from <thing> import *` statement.

I was able to "fix" the unresolved reference by manually adding `DAQmxCreateTask` to `PyDAQmx.__all__` and updating PyCharm skeletons. Not using `from PyDAQmx import *` will conveniently resolve the issue for you and also be best practice.

There isn't really anything you need to fix as a client of a library doing this kind of dynamic function creation at runtime, but in theory the library maintainer could set `__all__` to a manual set of symbols they expect to be defined dynamically from that `NIDAQmxBase.h` file to resolve the issue for clients.